# A problem with Yarn Install after GitHub Clone

Tags: github, npm-install, yarnpkg

When I was working on an open source project on GitHub Clone, there was a problem with executing Yarn Install, what caused it?

[image]

[image]

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your project references a npm package that isn't publicly available.

`"@zeeis/velectron": "^17.0.0"`

That prefix is mapped in their [.npmrc](https://github.com/tanshuai/alphabiz/blob/main/.npmrc) to a GitHub Packages repo which we can also see in your log file, and you don't have the proper credentials to access that. It is also mentioned in one of their build files as being available at https://github.com/zeeis/velectron/releases/download/ which also isn't public.

I couldn't find any information about what that package is on GitHub or even Google so it seems to be an internal component. You might want to raise an issue in the projects repository to see if they will make all components required to build available to the public.

I'm honestly not even sure I would call this project "open source" right now since not anyone can get the sources and build the application for themselves.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, it should not be called open source

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solutions.

1. just execute `npm install`
2. Delete yarn-lock file.
3. npm logout